# How to calculate number of days between two dates in one column in R

Tags: r, difftime

I have the following two data frames:

```
Date <- seq(as.Date("2013/1/1"), by = "day", length.out = 17)
x <-data.frame(Date)
x$discharge <- c("1000","1100","1200","1300","1400","1200","1300","1300","1200","1100","1200","1200","1100","1400","1200","1100","1400")
x$discharge <- as.numeric(x$discharge)
```

And

```
Date2 <- c("2013-01-01","2013-01-08","2013-01-12","2013-01-17")
y <- data.frame(Date2)
y$concentration <- c("1.5","2.5","1.5","3.5")
y$Date2 <- as.Date(y$Date2)
y$concentration <- as.numeric(y$concentration)
```

I was trying to calculate the number of days from one date to the other with the following code:

```
y %>%
    mutate(BETWEEN0=as.numeric(difftime(Date2,lag(Date2,1))),BETWEEN=ifelse(is.na(BETWEEN0),0,BETWEEN0))%>%
    select(-BETWEEN0)
```

Resulting in:

```
Date2         concentration BETWEEN
1 2013-01-01           1.5       0
2 2013-01-08           2.5       7
3 2013-01-12           1.5       4
4 2013-01-17           3.5       5
```

However, what I would need is the number of days calculated between two dates printed next to the first date etc, e.g.

```
Date2         concentration BETWEEN
1 2013-01-01           1.5       7
2 2013-01-08           2.5       4
3 2013-01-12           1.5       5
4 2013-01-17           3.5       0
```

That means that from 2013-01-01 to 2013-01-07 are 7 days, from 2013-01-08 to 2013-01-12 are 4 days etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
y%>%mutate(Between=as.numeric(lead(Date2,default = last(Date2))-Date2))
       Date2 concentration Between
1 2013-01-01           1.5       7
2 2013-01-08           2.5       4
3 2013-01-12           1.5       5
4 2013-01-17           3.5       0


y%>%mutate(Between=as.numeric(c(diff(Date2),0)))
       Date2 concentration Between
1 2013-01-01           1.5       7
2 2013-01-08           2.5       4
3 2013-01-12           1.5       5
4 2013-01-17           3.5       0
```

in base R:

```
 transform(y,Between=as.numeric(c(diff(Date2),0)))
```

Comment: That´s what I was after. Could you please explain the code if possible?

Comment: Its exactly wahat you did. only that you do a difference between each @Matt consecutive date2, then you add a zero at the end.. ie `c(diff(Date2)),0)` since the vector lacks onevalue. Also for the `lead`, you subtract the current value from the next value, and for the last value, you subtract the current from the current since there is no next